# How do I fix my GUI and package manager, after having removed nvidia-prime?

Tags: drivers, graphics

After updating the graphics driver, I could not get into graphical mode. So I removed the nvidia and xserver packages, and now, when I run `apt-get -f install`, I get these error messages:

[image: Photograph of a screen, showing a text-only console, with kernel messages and APT error messages.]

---

It is the **Elementary OS Freya 0.4** x86_64. It all started when I wanted to install Unity 8, and later I "installed" package `nvidia-304`, although I had installed `nvidia-340`.

I think it does not matter now, because I do not have any of these packages.

I managed to remove the `nvidia-prime` package using these commands:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<packagename>.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --removed --force-remove-reinstreq <packagename>
sudo apt-get remove <packagename>
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

But now I have a similar problem with a package `libc-bin`, when I want to install anything, which no longer I can not remove:

[image: Photograph of a screen, showing a text-only console, indicating several xorg-related packages not yet being configured, saying "Processing triggers for libc-bin" and concluding "/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)."]

This seems to me like a grave error of dpkg. I do not know whether it would be best to re-install and configure the package manager. What do you think?

Comment: How did you update the graphics driver? If you're downloading from Nvidia's website, you're doing it wrong. I recommend performing a clean installation of Ubuntu and then running the command `sudo apt install nvidia-current` to install your graphics drivers.

Comment: Of course, it is the Elementary OS. I updated my question about these and other informations.

Comment: I installed it through APT, like everything. I could re-install the system, but my cd-rom is dead, and my motherboard does not support USB boot.

Comment: So it is "of course" not Ubuntu. So it is off-topic.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall libc-bin`